# have only readonly access to kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kubernetes-dashboard-1.7.1 and I have set the clusterrole to view and I am still able to Delete/Scale/edit yaml which is not what i want. The dashboard needs to be readonly so they can only view logs and not be able to do any more actions

How can I get rid of the option.

Comment: this includes the create button at the right top

Answer (score 0):

Your cluster should have rbac disabled. [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)